# Optimizing code with multple conditions on multiple tables?

Tags: sql

I want to check whether these customers have **LEAD** action or **SELL** action which both stay in another tables. However, It takes like forever to finish it.

```
create table ct_nguyendang.visitor 
as
select user_id, updated_at::date,

case
    when user_id in (select distinct d_visitor_id from xiti.lead_detail) then 'lead'
    else 'None'
end as lead_action,

case
    when user_id in (select distinct account_id from ct_nguyendang.daily_listor) then 'sell'
    else 'None'
end as sell_action
```

Comment: Please provide asmple data and desired results.

Comment: Doesn't look like SQL Server code with CTAS

Comment: This doesn't look like SQL Server code to me. AFAIK, SQL Server doesn't support create table as select

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use `union all` and aggregation:

```
select user_id, max(is_lead) as has_lead, max(is_sale) as has_sale
from ((select d_visitor_id as user_id, 1 as is_lead, 0 as is_sale
       from xiti.lead_detail
      ) union all
      (select account_id, 0, 1
       from ct_nguyendang.daily_listor
      )
     ) ls
group by user_id;
```

If you have a table of users, then you can use correlated subqueries:

```
select u.*,
       (case when exists (select 1
                          from xiti.lead_detail l
                          where u.user_id = l.d_visitor_id
                         )
             then 1 else 0
        end) as has_lead,
       (case when exists (select 1
                          from ct_nguyendang.daily_listor s
                          where u.user_id = s.account_id
                         )
             then 1 else 0
        end) as has_sale
from users u;
```

Note that I prefer using `1` for "true" and `0` for "false".  Of course, you can use string values if you prefer.

To optimize this query, you want indexes on `xiti.lead_detail(d_visitor_id)` and `ct_nguyendang.daily_listor(account_id)`.